# How to get changes from the model into the modelview?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, model

I'm currently busy with rewriting an application into MVVM (in stages, because it is a lot of work).

Currently I can fill listviews and controls depending on changes in the model view and also listview selections are coupled correctly (at least I know how I can do it correctly).

However, I was wondering about changes in the model to be reflected in the modelview (and thus in the view). Should I add INotifyPropertyChange interfaces on all items in the model and subscribe on the modelview (maybe even like a chain if I want to subscribe to an item that is not in the 'top' of the model hierarchy)?

E.g. I have a list A containing a list B etc. Do I need to subscribe in list A for property changes of list B and in the model view subscribe to list A? And unsubscribe if another list selection is made (resulting in a lot of unsubscribe and new subscribe items)?

Thanks for reading/answering.

Comment: Can you provide a little bit of sample code, for context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, typically you would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on your models, and subscribe in your view models. If you are using a framework such as [CSLA](http://www.lhotka.net/cslanet/) for your business entities, then Rocky describes an anemic vs rich model, where in the later you expose the model directly to the view on your view model as a property.

I think `INotifyPropertyChanged` is a stable dependency, so it doesn't pollute your models significantly. Some people do not like exposing the model directly to the view, but I find it saves a lot or repeat code. You may find that if you don't, your view models end up duplicating many of the properties on your model, without adding any value.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I also don't think INotifyPropertyChanged implementations don't pullute my models. However, I need to have them in the ViewModel (I think it's better than in the view itself) or am I misunderstanding you? Also I need to copy at least the properties I need in my ModelView, because I can't connect them to anywhere in the model.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. You would implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your model, as well as on your view model. If you were happy with exposing the model to the view, then you would have a Model property on your view model, of type YourModel. Your view model may also have additional properties to shape the model data to the view. E.g. your view model may have an Age property, where your model only has a DateOfBirth property. The view doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged, but subscribes to the PropertyChanged event (this is done automatically with the XAML binding engine).

Comment: Ok I think we mean the same. If I understand you well, I have to put a PropertyChanged method in my ModelView and it should listen to the model. These listen to various parts of the model and set properties which are coupled via XAML.

Comment: Yesterday I continued with my app for a bit, however I need to fix several items before I can continue with trying this solution (which probably works but I can't implement it yet). I will react as soon as I have finished implemented this solution.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand right, you want to programmatically change your data in the model and show the updated data via the viewmodel accordingly?

I would suggest you change the viewmodel properties in your code instead and only use the models for loading/saving the data, that would eliminate that problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is it that strange to change the data inside the model? It's done in the ViewModel, but the model then is changed and I guess I have to subscribe to changes inside the model. So when changing the model via the ViewModel, I want the (same) ViewModel to listen to changes in the model to reflect its changes in the Window (connected to that ViewModel).

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem: When you implement the property getter/setter yourself to map the property to the model property, e.g. `get { return _model.MyProperty; } set { _model.MyProperty = value; OnPropertyChanged("MyProperty"); }`, you will get the gui and the model updated. You never have to access the model property in code anywhere except in the viewmodel property reflecting the model property...

Comment: I understand that part, but if the model is changed and I want a notification of it in the ModelView, I need to subscribe to a lot of items on various places in the model, which also need to be unsubscribed when e.g. a new selection on a listview is made. Maybe I should add some code above but I'm afraid it will be so much nobody will take the time to read it.

Comment: whatever clarifies the question will help. You can also give a precise example of the workflow you are doing

Comment: I will give an example as soon as I have tried the solution which I accepted (which will probably work). Or at least tried if partially, but at this point I need to find the time to implement it. I will edit my question later (also if it worked).